# Localize member caption in Mondrian schema

Tags: mdx, olap, olap-cube, mondrian

Is there a way how I can localize captions of members in Mondrian schema? I know I can localize names (captions) of cubes/hiearchies/dimensions/levels using [localizing schema processor](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/schema.php#I18n), but I do not see a way how to localize names of individual members.

Suppose we have dimension named `product` with list of products. Our current structure is that for every descriptive column we have translation, something like:

- product_key
- product_group_en
- product_type_en
- product_name_en
- product_group_cs
- product_type_cs
- product_name_cs

Is there a way how I can map these columns to schema so correct language is displayed based on user's locale (en/cs/default)?

Our current solution is to have two hierarchies (one for each language) in every dimension, but this is not very elegant.